# How to keep grouped variables together in training and test data

Tags: r, group-by, linear-regression, training-data

I'm making and testing the accuracy of age extrapolations from growth measurements and to do this I have to split my data into my training and test data.

The issue is that individuals in my data set were measured multiple times and sometimes they were measured twice, sometimes 3 times. In the dataset Birds is the individual chick, age is the age at measurement, and wing is that measurement value.

I've tried using the group_by function to keep their measurements together, but this doesn't seem to work. I also tried nesting the data but that puts the data in a new table and my code doesn't like that. Is there another way I could keep the groups together while still randomly assigning them to training and test data?

```
library('tidyverse')
library("ggplot2")
library("readxl")
library("writexl")
library('dplyr')
library('Rmisc')
library('cowplot')
library('purrr')
library('caTools')
library('MLmetrics')

Bird<-c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,10,10,)
Age<-c(10,17,27,17,28,10,17,27,10,17,10,17,28,10,17,28,10,17,28,10,17,28,10,17,28,11,18,)
Wing<-c(39,63,98,61,99,34,48,80,30,37,35,51,71,40,55,79,34,47,77,36,55,84,35,55,88,36,59,)
Set14<-data.frame(Bird, Age, Wing) %>% 
  group_by(Bird) 
Set14$Bird<-as.factor((Set14$Bird))
Set14

sample_size = floor(0.7*nrow(Set14))

picked = sample(seq_len(nrow(Set14)),size = sample_size)
Training =Set14[picked,]
Training
Test =Set14[-picked,]
Test

trm<-lm(Age~Wing, data=Training)

predval<-predict(object=trm,
                 newdata=Test)
predval

error<-data.frame(actual=Test$Age, calculated=predval)
error

MAPE(error$actual, error$calculated)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Base R you could do:

```
a <- as.integer(Set14$Bird)
train_index <- a %in% sample(n<-length(unique(a)), 0.7*n) 
train <- set14[train, ]
test <- set14[!train, ]
```

in Tidyverse:

```
ungroup(Set14) %>%
  nest_by(Bird) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(tt = floor(.7*n()),
     tt = sample(rep(c('train', 'test'), c(tt[1], n()-tt[1])))) %>%
  unnest(data) %>%
  group_split(tt, .keep = FALSE)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  Bird    Age  Wing
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1        10    39
2 1        17    63
3 1        27    98
4 3        10    34
5 3        17    48
6 3        27    80
7 7        10    34
8 7        17    47
9 7        28    77

[[2]]
# A tibble: 18 x 3
   Bird    Age  Wing
   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2        17    61
 2 2        28    99
 3 4        10    30
 4 4        17    37
 5 5        10    35
 6 5        17    51
 7 5        28    71
 8 6        10    40
 9 6        17    55
10 6        28    79
11 8        10    36
12 8        17    55
13 8        28    84
14 9        10    35
15 9        17    55
16 9        28    88
17 10       11    36
18 10       18    59
```

Comment: This seems to be splitting the variable of Bird apart in the training and test data, I want that variable to stay together in the sets so that all of the 1's are in the same set, all of the 2's are in the same set and so on

Comment: @arikabraschuk your question is not clear, because  your data itself as it is contains all the ones, all the twos. You dont want to split the data, so what do you want to do? Can you post in the question the output that you expect/want

Comment: I just updated the question to clarify, I realized that I didn't explain my variables well. I want to split the data into 70% and 30% to make a linear model with the 70% of measurements, and the bird variable is just telling which bird the measurement belongs to. Because some birds have 2 measurements and some have 3, I want to keep the measurements per individual grouped together in the same dataset rather than splitting them. Hope that clarifies

Comment: @arikabraschuk Now that clariefs alot. Give me moment will update

Comment: @arikabraschuk check the edit